# how to remove the scroll and adjust the adaptability?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please help to remove the scroll that appears when the window's width is 992px < width < 1006px
(For convenience, I brought in a header width).

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=fbddbcf1a87480d1bf27#media-queries-breakpoints) are my settings for bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=fbddbcf1a87480d1bf27#media-queries-breakpoints
 
It is important to me that the distance between *.bg_blue_innerpo* continued to be 66px, and the width *.page-header* 992px.

Comment: Please provide a site example or code (html/css) snippet in here and a Fiddle, if possible. If you are missing a row you can get a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: http://prozaik.16mb.com/html5_2/bootstrap2/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the breakpoint for medium (992) and small (768):

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
width: 1006px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
width: 786px;
}
```

Your container is, in essence, larger than the breakpoint (width of screen) which is causing a scrollbar.

Is there any reason why you have changed the default breakpoint structure?